# How do I use a custom comparator in a TreeMultiSet?

Tags: java, guava, comparator

I want to use a custom `Comparator` for a `TreeMultiSet`. Here's what I do:

```
public static class OccurenceComparator implements Comparator<Multiset.Entry<String>>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Multiset.Entry<String> e1, Multiset.Entry<String> e2) {
        return e2.getCount() - e1.getCount() ;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    Comparator<Multiset.Entry<String>> occurenceComparator = new OccurenceComparator();
    Multiset<String> treeMultiSet = TreeMultiset.create(occurenceComparator);
}
```

Here's what I get:

> Unresolved compilation problem:
>         The method `create(Comparator<? super E>)` in the type `TreeMultiset` is not applicable for the arguments
>   `(Comparator<Multiset.Entry<String>>)`

I'm stumped

Comment: The comparator compares keys not entries. Should be of type Comparator<String> in your instance

Comment: But I want to compare based on the number of times they have appeared in the Multiset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Multiset is `Multiset<String>`, so shouldnt your comparator compare `String`s? That looks to be what the Compiler expects.

```
public static class OccurenceComparator implements Comparator<String>{
```

Comment: But I don't have a String.getCount(), what do I do about that?

Comment: ...You shouldn't use a `TreeMultiset` that sorts by elements, then.  You should use something like [`Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html#copyHighestCountFirst(com.google.common.collect.Multiset)).

Comment: What should I use? I thought that was guava's sorted multiset.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I will look for that method. It appears I don't have a good enough version of guava.

Comment: remember this function is likely used to insert as well as sort.

Comment: Maven dependency management is not trivial, is there a way I tell directly from my code what version of Guava I'm using? Maybe something along the lines of Multisets.getVersion()? I never can get the "copyHighestCountFirst" method to compile.

Comment: To see what version of Guava you depend on, use: `mvn dependency:tree | less`

By looking at the output, you can tell what version of Guava you depend on, check if there are multiple versions (and which transitive dependencies to exclude), and make sure that you don't depend by mistake on the google-collections artifact.